# Rotate object in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help to understand the management of objects. At the moment, there is a rotation of the object. I want the arrow to rotate, and the angle of rotation depends on the current X and Y coordinates. Unity2D.
Now it is left (does not rotate), but it needs to be right (it always rotates and looks in one direction), but I don’t know how to calculate the degrees for rotation.

`

```
public float angle = 0; // угол 
    public float radius = 0.5f; // радиус
    public bool isCircle = false; // условие движения по кругу
    public float speed = 5f;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        angle += Time.deltaTime; // меняется значение угла
        var x = Mathf.Cos(angle * speed) * radius + parent.position.x;
        var y = Mathf.Sin(angle * speed) * radius + parent.position.y;
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y,0);
        //transform.Rotate(0, 0, a);
    }
```

`

Help me, how to calculate angle?

Answer (score 0):

You need [`Mathf.Atan2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Atan2.html), it will return a radian, then you need to multiply a Mathf.Rad2Deg to get the Euler angle.

Comment: Use the Euler angle, but rotation is not 360 =(

`alpha = Mathf.Atan2(y , x)* Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0 ,0, alpha));`